# Service script for gitea always return stop/waiting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I use Ubuntu 14.04 (upstart 1.12.1) and successfully install gitea [by follow this guide](https://gist.github.com/appleboy/36313a525fbef673f8aefadb9c0f8247). However I can't write a service script to start/stop it. My script likes this:

```
start on filesystem
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c git --exec /home/git/runGit.sh
#/home/git/runGit.sh
#screen -dmS git "/home/git/gitea web"
```

When I run:
`sudo service gitea start`

It's always return `gitea stop/waiting`. But if I manually run /home/git/runGit.sh from user git: it works? What's wrong?

```
t@t-VirtualBox:~$ sudo service gitea start 
[sudo] password for wiki: 
gitea stop/waiting t@t-VirtualBox:~$ 
echo $? 0
```

Comment: Random Guess : As [man start-stop-daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) says "*that It scans the process table looking for any processes which match the process name, parent pid, uid, and/or gid (if specified). Any matching process will prevent --start from starting the daemon.*"  I see that you have passed `git` as a `chuid`, So It maybe the case that `--start` options finds that chuid and exits simply. Please provide the exit status by typing `echo $?` on terminal after your script exits out.

Comment: `t@t-VirtualBox:~$ sudo service gitea start
[sudo] password for wiki:
gitea stop/waiting
t@t-VirtualBox:~$ echo $?
0`
Thank for the headups.

Comment: As you requested, sorry I didn't check the result in comment